# (Beginner) Error when loading 'python manage.py runserver' on Visual Studio Code part of Django project

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to this and am currently learning Django on Visual Studio Code using a Mac.

I'm getting a few errors and was wondering if someone could help.

**File structure and activating virtualenv**

I go here to activate the virtual env:

> /Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/

The project is located here, and this is where I runserver/where the manage.py file is :

> /Users/username/Desktop/VSC/Projects/firstproject

When I try to run my project through virtualenv I get the following error in the Terminal:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/VSC/Projects/VSC/VSC/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Then it seem's to kick me out of the virtualenv, and I have to go back to activating it via opening a new shell.

Also, I'm getting a bunch of squiggly red lines under my *from* when I'm trying to import things into my project. For example, in the 'views.py' file at the top I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
```

I'm assuming it is not importing the things I have stated.

I've tried to add as much info as possible, like I said I'm new at this. But if you need any more information or if I've missed something - than do let me know and I will post it up.

The following is from my urls.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I pip freeze, this is what is coming up within the virtualenv:

```
(test) Usernames-MacBook-Pro:test username$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.3.3
Django==3.0.5
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.4.4
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
wrapt==1.11.2
```

*Which terminal are you running the command in*

I'm running the 'bash' terminal, when I get the error and I get kicked out it switches to 'Python'.

*how are you activating the virtualenv*

I activate the virtualenv by going to the folder (using terminal) and typing in:

```
source bin/activate
```

Comment: Please include your urls.py file so we can see if you've actually tried importing `include` or not. Which terminal are you running the command in, how are you activating the virtualenv, and maybe include an output of `pip freeze` from within your virtualenv (with it activated) so we can see what packages are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your project without virtual environment and then check again

> python3 manage.py runserver

It should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and got the following response  :

Comment: {Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?}

Answer (score 0):

Adam, the answer is in the last 2 lines of the error. It looks like you are trying to "include" something you imported into the url file? You don't need to do that, you would just write it as path('', calc.urls). Try that and see what happens.

```
path('', include('calc.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```